# Как определить уровень громкости сигнала поступающего на микрофон

Tags: android, аудио

Подскажите, как можно определить уровень громкости сигнала поступающего на микрофон телефона. (упрощенно, интересует максимальное значение в конкретный момент, по отношению к какому-то эталонному).
Как вариант, также интересует возможность определить максимальное значение громкости в записанном файле.
Нашел следующий код, но возвращаемой значение постоянно равно 0

```
int maxa = 0;
    int minSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(16000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    AudioRecord ar = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 16000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minSize);
    short[] buffer = new short[minSize];
    ar.read(buffer, 0, minSize);
    for (short s : buffer) {
        if (Math.abs(s) > maxa)
            maxa = Math.abs(s);
    }
    ar.stop();
    return maxa;
```

В манифесте указал `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181449/android-detect-sound-level

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно!